# Instrumentation testing of a custom view

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have created a custom view that is used to build a form dynamically. A form configuration is fetched from a server and the custom view then renders a form (edittexts, checkboxes, etc...) based on what is specified in the configuration.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to test the custom view. The view itself extends LinearLayout and follows the MVP pattern so any logic that could be extracted to the Presenter layer has been and is covered under a unit test. Now my goal is to run a UI test to ensure that the view works properly and to find regressions. For example, the server might return a configuration that requires that two EditTexts have character limits of 5 characters. I want to be able to build a form, enter text into the two EditTexts and ensure that their input length has been limited to 5 characters.

So what's the proper way to do this?

Is there a way to test just the view itself using instrumentation testing or will the view always need to be in the layout of an activity or fragment in order to test it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to test just the view itself using instrumentation testing or will the view always need to be in the layout of an activity or fragment in order to test it?

You cannot test the view separately. During instrumentation test an apk is being built and installed on the device. As you can conclude, your apk cannot consist only of your custom view, it's a normal android application.

What you will end up is, that you'd perform actions (e.g. [ViewActions.typeText("some text")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#typeText(java.lang.String)) in `EditText` with `some id`) and then perform validations (check, that the `EditText` with `some id` has `some text` as it's content).

As long as you deal with custom view, it's possible that you'd have to create your custom [ViewMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html).